# Why MB_CUR_MAX is un-defined?

Tags: c++

I just copy some codes from [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/wctomb/), and run the test program for `wctomb`:

```
/* wctomb example */
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <stdlib.h>     /* wctomb, wchar_t(C) */

int main() {
  const wchar_t str[] = L"wctomb example";
  const wchar_t* pt;
  char buffer [MB_CUR_MAX];
  int i,length;

  pt = str;
  while (*pt) {
    length = wctomb(buffer,*pt);
    if (length<1) break;
    for (i=0;i<length;++i) printf ("[%c]",buffer[i]);
    ++pt;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

However, the program cannot be compiled because MB_CUR_MAX is undefined as far as my compiler (VC 2010) is considered. I was wondering what I should do. Thanks!

```
error C2057: expected constant expression
error C2466: cannot allocate an array of constant size 0
error C2133: 'buffer' : unknown size
```

Answer (score 3):

`MB_CUR_MAX` is defined as function call `#define MB_CUR_MAX ___mb_cur_max_func()`, thus you have to calculate it runtime and allocate array dynamically.

Answer (score 3):

Unlike many of the pre-processor defined numbers, MB_CUR_MAX is *not* required to be a constant. In fact, since it's locale-dependent, I'm not sure it can ever be a compile-time constant.

MS defines it like:

```
#ifndef MB_CUR_MAX
#define MB_CUR_MAX ___mb_cur_max_func()
```

The code you give above *would* be legitimate in C99 or C11, where `char buffer [MB_CUR_MAX];` would be a variable length array -- but based on the tag, you're trying to compile it as C++, which doesn't include VLAs (and Microsoft doesn't implement C99 anyway, so no VLAs in its C mode either).

If you're going to compile as C++, you probably want to change that from an array to a `std::vector`, so specifying a size that isn't a compile-time constant is no longer a problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep using a static buffer (which is better, although I agree with Jerry that a `std::vector` is the way to go), use `MB_LEN_MAX` instead.